# difference between *.so file created by pybind and regular linux dynamic libs

Tags: python, pybind11

When one uses [pybind](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to create python-c++ bindings, upon compilation pybind creates a `*.so` file. AFAIK the compilation step in pybind just uses the c++ compiler, so this should be no different from just regular shared libs that one would create for a normal c++ code. How does the python interpreter introspect into these `*.so` files to notice that there are python-compatible modules in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you'll want to look at the CPython docs for how C extensions work. From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html

> A C extension for CPython is a shared library (e.g. a .so file on Linux, .pyd on Windows), which exports an initialization function.

As it says here, the primary difference is that it defines its initialization / entry point function.

All `pybind` does is wrap this entry point via `PYBIND11_MODULE`:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#creating-bindings-for-a-simple-function
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/25abf7e/include/pybind11/detail/common.h#L283